# How to route shifter cables along frame to a Rohloff external gear mech?

Tags: cable-routing

I am currently converting my Rohloff's gear mech from the internal to external version, and I’d like to route the shifter cables along the downtube and chainstay. However, I’m not sure how to route the cables from the shifter on the right side of the handlebars to the gear mech on the left side of the rear wheel. What attachments might I need for this beyond any brazes on my Surly LHT (non-disc) frame? Does anyone have a few high-definition photos they could share of their working and time-tested setup?

Comment: I can take some, but my solution might not impress you as I use cable ties. The route is just from the right handlebar, down the left side of the top tube, down the left seatstay through the rack and to the shifter box. Albeit I don't have a Rohloff in an upright diamond frame, but the routing issues seem pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid routing the Rohloff shifter cables along the top tube. That's the setup I already have, and the top tube and rear brake area feels a bit cluttered. I’m looking specifically for info on downtube and chainstay routing.

Comment: Don't you just strap the cables to the tubes you prefer? I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: My own shifter cables run down the bottom of my bottom tube. But I have a specialized sirrus sport, so my frame might be different.

Comment: Study cable arrangements on similar frames.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. Am I just supposed to simply strap the Rohloff shifter cables in their full housing to the downtube with zip ties? (And if so, is it necessary to keep the cables taut by attaching to the rear chainstay too?) Or should I route them like derailleur cables on each side of the downtube by using the brazes, and then have the cable passing down the right side of the downtube routed to the left chainstay under the bottom bracket? (In which case, what is a quality way of doing this that looks like it corresponds to the quality of the Rohloff hub in general?)

Comment: You *should* do whatever makes you happy. We can't tell you that. Rohloff cables should have full housing from the shifter to the hub, but apart from that it's up to you. In my velomobile I just ran them across the floor with no attachment to the bike except at the ends.

Comment: @Móż **don't think you are alone in this!** Lousy eyelets with always popping plastic holders ain't telling me how to route my wire and hydraulic lines. Also interrupting the housing on the bottom of the bottom tube so we "reduce stretch"? No way I'm cutting my housing exactly where the most mud and sand flies in!

Answer (score 1):

As you have a steel frame, you will get the best result if you have a competent framebuilder add the appropriate brazeons. There are two sorts of brazeons that one could use:

- Cable tie guides, where the cable housing is fixed in a groove with a small cable tie (looks much better than a big cable tie around the entire tube!)
- various shapes of short tubes or rings, where the cable housing is fed through

Have a look at [Ceeway](http://www.framebuilding.com/Braze%20ons.htm) for what is available (or talk to your framebuilder).

For a visually pleasing end result, the frame will need a new paint job after adding brazeons.